# trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty error | Gradle | Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, java-8, android-sdk-manager

I've been trying to create an Android app from Angular using Cordova and JDK 8.
After running `cordova build android` I get this error:
component versions:

1. Angular 9
2. Gradle 7
3. Cordova 10
4. SDKmanager 5

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Things I've tried:

1. renaming `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip` to `http` but it renames itself again to `https`
2. reinstalling JDK 8
3. Run CMD/Powershell as Administrator

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with the JDK 8. I instead used a JDK from another community. You can download it from this address:
`https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild`

works fine